# Javascript: How to add to a set max value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a constant but that constant will decrease so as to not add over the max set value.
The example below will work just fine but what if `var val` is not set to a number divisible by 10?
So if it were at 41-49 I would like to change the value of constant to equal values 9-1 so that it can reach the max set value. I know I can just loop between values 41-49 but that would be less efficient than I would like it too.

```
var val = 0;
var maxval = 50;
var constant = 10;

if(val < maxval){
    val += self.constant;
}
```

an example of what I am trying to not receive is below with an output of 54 instead of the max 50

```
var val = 0;
var maxval = 50;
var constant = 10;

if(val < maxval){
    val -= 1;
    val += self.constant;
}
```

Comment: If the input is 37, what would you want? 47, or 40?

Comment: "I am trying to add a constant but that constant will decrease" - so, it's not a `constant` as the value changes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.min`, once the new value goes more than `maxval`, maxval will be the value.

```
var val = 0;
var maxval = 50;
var constant = 10;
function updateMax() {
  val = Math.min(val + constant, maxval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just add and if over max, set it to the max

```
val += self.constant;
if(val > maxval) {
  val = maxval
}
```